# Xcode Interface Builder Misplaced Views / Fix Misplacement Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

When I move an item (button, label, view, whatever) either by dragging it or changing the values in the attributes inspector, (it seems) more often than not I get a yellow "misplaced view" warning and have to go "Update constraints".  Other times this does not happen.

What is the secret to when this happens and when it does not?  I am using Auto Layout and Size Classes. I am using Xcode 7, but it seems to have been this way for a while, it's not new behavior.

What is this newbie missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The "Update Constraints" option is kind of weird because Xcode would have to "guess" what we want and usually it will guess it wrong. I think the best approach is to directly change the values of the constraints (or the constraints themselves - you can clear the constraints of an object and set the new ones, or just select and delete each of them) to the ones that represent what you want for your UI.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but I'm telling Xcode exactly what I want and sometimes it takes it and sometimes it doesn't.  I'm going to keep this open in case anyone else can add more insight.